# Using Autodesk BIM360 account to login to auth0

Tags: autodesk-forge, auth0, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

we have a webapp, that uses authentication via auth0. Now we want to connect bim360 to our solution. Therefore we need to use the bim360 login / token to proceed in auth0.

Unfortunately there is no Autodesk account provider in auth0 providers listed.

Is there a chance to support the autodesk login / autodesk id in auht0?

Comment: i think its possible to setup any identity provider to work with Auth0. I have not done it but i think you can start here - https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/oidc

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that Autodesk OAuth doesn't support OpenId Connect and other 3rd parties' methods. Therefore, you cannot connect auth0 with BIM360, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, bad news... So, what can we do if we need to sign in to bim360 AND some other environment?

Comment: If you're an [enterprise customer of Autodesk](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide/files/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide-Access-to-SSO-html-html.html), you may use the [Autodesk Enterprise SSO service](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide/files/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide-About-Single-Sign-on-SSO-html-html.html) to sign in to Autodesk services with your enterprise credentials, but you will have to consider extra costs from your side.

Comment: Refer here for the [Autodesk Premium Plan](https://www.autodesk.com/campaigns/premium-plan?geoNavigationPreferredSite=US)

Comment: Any news since 2020 to add Autodesk as social login in Auth0 ?